# How can I run my python script when I start my NextJS app

Tags: python, flask, next.js, large-language-model

I am working on the popular chat with PDF projects. The way I have mine setup is to have all the LLM code in a Python script and use Flask to set it up as an API I can call from the front end. Right now, when I start the app I do the normal "npm run dev" and then I also have to do "python llmpython.py" to start my Python script. What's an efficient way to do this such that when my app starts, the Python script also starts? If I make this online, how would it work also?

Here's my llmpython.py file:

```
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

#Setting Environment variables
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()
OPENAI_API_KEY = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')



# app instance
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
@cross_origin()
@app.route("/api/home", methods=['POST'])
def chat_document():
    data = request.get_json()
    pdfUrl = data['url']
    query = data['chat']

    #Load PDF
    #The url should be coming from the front end through a post request
    loader = PyPDFLoader(pdfUrl)
    if loader:
        data = loader.load_and_split()
    else:
        return "Error loading PDF"

    #Text Splitting
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
    texts = text_splitter.split_documents(data)

    #Embedding and vector storage
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)
    vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(texts, embeddings)

    #query
    # query = "What's the main point of the document?"
    docs = vectorstore.similarity_search(query)

    #Load LLM and chatchain
    llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)
    chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff")
    llmresponse = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)

    response = jsonify({
        'message': llmresponse,
        'role': 'ai'
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    return response


@app.route("/api/guest", methods=['POST'])
def guest_document():
    data = request.get_json()
    pdfUrl = data['url']
    query1 = data['chat1']
    query2 = data['chat2']

    #Load PDF
    #The url should be coming from the front end through a post request
    loader = PyPDFLoader(pdfUrl)
    if loader:
        data = loader.load_and_split()
    else:
        return "Error loading PDF"

    #Text Splitting
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
    texts = text_splitter.split_documents(data)

    #Embedding and vector storage
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)
    vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(texts, embeddings)

    #query
    # query = "What's the main point of the document?"
    docs1 = vectorstore.similarity_search(query1)
    docs2 = vectorstore.similarity_search(query2)

    #Load LLM and chatchain
    llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)
    chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff")
    llmresponse1 = chain.run(input_documents=docs1, question=query1)
    llmresponse2 = chain.run(input_documents=docs2, question=query2)
    response = jsonify({
        'message1': llmresponse1,
        'message2': llmresponse2,
        'role': 'ai'
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

and this is one of the components where I am calling the flask app from:

```
import { fileName, guestpdfUrl } from "@/components/Hero";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { useState } from "react";
import TabsSec from "./TabsSec";

const Guest = () => {
  const [summary, setSummary] = useState<string>(""); // <-- specify type here
  const [bulletSummary, setBulletSummary] = useState<string>(""); // <-- specify type here
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false); // <-- specify type here

  const processDocument = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);

    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/guest", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        url: guestpdfUrl,
        chat1: "Create a summary of this text",
        chat2: "Create a 10 bullet point summary of this text",
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.message2);
        setSummary(data.message1);
        setBulletSummary(data.message2);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };



  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
      <div className=" text-[#202942] mb-4 text-4xl md:text-5xl tracking-tight font-extrabold">
        Welcome Guest
      </div>
      <div className=" text-[#202942]  my-4 text-center text-xl md:text-2xl tracking-tight font-extrabold">
        You&apos;ve uploaded a PDF called {fileName}
      </div>
      <div className="mb-8">
        <Button
          className="rounded-full bg-[#202942] text-[#dfeff4] 
           hover:bg-[#3a435e]
         font-bold text-sm md:text-base py-2 px-3"
          onClick={processDocument}
        >
          Process Document
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div></div>
      <TabsSec
        summary={summary}
        bulletSummary={bulletSummary}
        isLoading={isLoading}
      />{" "}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Guest;
```

How would you advice that I achieve this. I was thinking of using an exec childprocess to run "python llmpython.py" in a useEffect but it looks like that is not possible. I would appreciate any advice

Comment: you should deploy the python backend and make a request in `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

there is a tool called supervisor which allows you to manage background processes and get error and out logs. I recommend you to run your python app with gunicorn+supervisor. I don't know too much about NextJS but https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/deploying-nextjs-app check this out.

Also do not forget to run them on different ports and not use the port `80` and `443` directly. Instead use a proxy like `NGINX`. Also make sure your flask API is available outside of localhost after setting up, which means you need to use `host=yourdomain.com` in order to access from nextjs.

Here is a video that may help:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goToXTC96Co&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&index=13